# Close XPages ExtLib dialog from inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, dialog, xpages, xpages-extlib

I have db1.nsf/doc1 open in an XPage. On the XPage is a view of of related documents (db2.nsf/doc2) on the same server. I am using a repeat control with a link wrapped around each entry to open doc2 in an ExtLib dialog.

Note: Because doc2 has fileUpload and fileDownload controls on it, I have to open doc2 in an iframe in the dialog (v8.5.3). I have all the file upload/download stuff working thanks to Toohey's article [File Upload XPage Forms via OpenNTF.org Extension Library Dialogs](http://www.dominoguru.com/page.xsp?id=xpage_fileupload_extlib_dialog_tutorial.html).

The problem is that I am unable to close the dialog with a button in the iframe in the dialog. The difference between my scenario and Toohey's is that I am working with 2 different documents in 2 different databases. The parent opener is an XPage with datasource doc1 in db1 while the dialog child is doc2 in db2. I don't seem to be able to get a handle on the parent document from within the child document in the iframe so i can close the dialog. It looks something like this:

```
<html><body>
<form action="db1.nsf/mainDoc.xsp?doc1&action=openDocument"></form>
<div id="dialog">
    <form action="db1.nsf/mainDoc.xsp?doc1&action=openDocument">
        <iframe src="showDialog.xsp?databaseName=db2.nsf&doc2">
            <html><body>
                <form action="db1.nsf/showDialog.xsp?databaseName=db2.nsf&doc2&action=editDocument">
                    <button id="okBtn" type="submit">OK</button>
                </form>
            </body></html>
        </iframe>
    </form>
</div>
</body></html>
```

*Note: showDialog.xsp is an XPage in db1 with it's datasource being db2.nsf/doc2. (I'm using xp:panel with tagName="iframe".)

I want the OK button to save the document (which it does) and close the dialog (which it doesn't). I have tried several different methods of "parent. ..." to get a handle on  and close it - with no success at all.

How do I get a handle on the dialog element from within the iframe so I can close it?

*Added server version.

Answer (score 0):

The way the XPages Extension Library dialog works is that it runs SSJS, then calls `view.postScript()` to pass CSJS back to the browser to close the dialog. You need to reproduce that. (I'm not sure what server version you're using but `view.postScript()` was only added in 8.5.3, probably for the dialog use case.)

I'm not familiar with the functionality you're using, but 9.0.1 provided the ability to upload attachments within a partial refresh, which resolves workarounds for Ext Lib dialogs.

The `databaseName` property of a datasource can be computed (format is serverName!!filePath), so data being in a separate database should not be an issue. Indeed most applications I build now separate XPages into one NSF and data / forms / views / agents in another. That application architecture is required anyway for XPages on Bluemix, and standard for other web application development.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use `view.postScript()` here. How would that be different from using the onComplete event on the OK button to get a handle on the dialog element and closing it? My problem appears to be that I can't a handle on `<div id="dialog">` from `<button id="okBtn" type="submit">OK</button>` inside the iframe. No matter how I put it in, `parent.document.getElementById('#{id:dialog}')` is null

Comment: Is this an Extension Library dialog (xe:dialog in the XML markup of the source pane in Domino Designer) or a normal HTML div with an ID? "#{id:....}" is code that runs on the *server* not the *browser* to work out the runtime ID of an XPages control. It won't get a handle on a normal HTML div.

Comment: `onComplete` runs regardless of success or failure. The submit will post to the server and return something, which may be a validation error. You only want to close if there's a successful save. Then and only then do you want to close the dialog. `view.postScript()` is in the SSJS, but it sounds like you're using basic HTML. I think the issue may be one to do with iframes rather than XPages components. It's hard without seeing the wider system architecture, but my recommendation would be to ensure both XPages are in the same NSF, that will significantly simplify using XPages components.

Comment: On a separate note, possibly of relevance, by using two different NSFs, the single web page has two different sets of applicationScope, sessionScope, viewScope etc. Whatever is set in one won't be available to the other, another reason for incorporating all XPages in the same NSF.